# Veronese Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Can anyone explain proposition 5.1 in these notes: [http://www.math.utah.edu/~bertram/6140/Examples.pdf](http://www.math.utah.edu/%7Ebertram/6140/Examples.pdf)

> What is the general map between the Veronese Variety and the image of the veronese map?
>
> If we consider the case $d=2$, $n=2$, we are supposed to have $\nu_{d}(\mathbb{P}^{2})$={[$X_{0}^{2}$,$X_{1}^{2}$, $X_{2}^2$, $X_{0}X_{1}$...]}= {[$Z_{0}$, $Z_{1}$, ...$Z_{n}$] such that
> $Z_{0}$, $Z_{1}$, ...$Z_{n}$ satisfy six quadratic polynomial equations $Z_{0}Z_{1}-Z_{3}^{2}$, $Z_{0}Z_{5}-Z_{4}Z_{3}$, $Z_{0}Z_{2}-Z_{4}Z_{4}$, $Z_{3}Z_{5}-Z_{4}Z_{1}$, $Z_{3}Z_{2}-Z_{4}Z_{5}$, $Z_{1}Z_{2}-Z_{5}Z_{5}$}:= the Veronese Variety.

clearly the image of the Veronese map is a subset of the Veronese Variety by substitution.

How to get the reverse inclusion?

Comment: Please use ">" to denote quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You never really specified the map so let me use Aaron's notation. If you're given a point $(x_0, \dots, x_5)$ in $\mathbf P^5$ satisfying these equations then you have to pretend it's really of the form $v_2(x,y,z)$ and try to recover $x,y,z$.

The first thing you notice is that one of $x_0, x_3, x_5$ had better be nonzero. Show that if they were all zero then the equations force $x_1, x_2$ to be zero as well, which is absurd.

So let's say $x_0 \neq 0$. Looking at the definition of $v_2$ again the hope is that our point is $v_2(x_0, x_1, x_2)$. Writing this out and using the equations:
\[
v_2(x_0,x_1,x_2) = (x_0^2, x_0x_1, x_0x_2, x_1^2 = x_0x_3, x_1x_2=x_0x_4,x_2^2=x_0x_5)
\]
Similarly, if $x_1 \neq 0$ then $v_2(x_1,x_3,x_4)$ works. The general Veronese is very similar.

Comment: I don't understand your use of $x_{0}...x_{5}$. Are they coordinates for the codomain $\mathbb{P}^{5}$ or for the domain $\mathbb{P}^{2}$?

Comment: @user352102 There are $6$ coordinates so I hope they're referring to $\mathbb P^6$, the target. I am following Bertram because he specifies everything.

Comment: Er, I mean $\mathbb P^5$. You know.